# Limit of a sum of complex exponentials

Tags: limits

Consider the limit

$$\lim_{L\rightarrow\infty }f_L(t)=\lim_{L\rightarrow\infty }\frac {1}{L^2}\left|\sum_{k=0}^{L-1}e^{it\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{L} k\right)}\right|^2 $$

I think I can get to this by computing the simpler limit

$$ g(t)=\lim_{L\to\infty}\frac{1}{L}\sum_{k=0}^{L-1}e^{it\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{L} k\right)}$$

I suspect that $g(t)=0$ for all $t\neq 0$, but I have no idea how to prove it. For $L$ even it is easy to see

$$ g_L(t)=\frac{1}{L}\sum_{k=0}^{L-1}e^{it\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{L} k\right)}=\frac 1L \left[\sum_{k=0}^{L/2-1}e^{it\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{L} k\right)}+\sum_{k=L/2}^{L-1}e^{it\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{L} k\right)}\right]=\frac 1L \left[\sum_{k=0}^{L/2-1}e^{it\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{L} k\right)}+\sum_{k=0}^{L/2-1}e^{it\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{L} k+L/2\right)}\right]=\\=\frac 1L \left[\sum_{k=0}^{L/2-1}e^{it\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{L} k\right)}+\sum_{k=0}^{L/2-1}e^{-it\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{L} k\right)}\right]=\frac{2}{L}\sum_{k=0}^{L/2-1}\cos\left({t\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{L} k\right)}\right)$$

I think that by playing with floor functions I can get the same for $L$ odd, but I don't thnik that'll help me. How can I compute this?

Edit: I think the limit can be expressed as an integral by thinking of it as a Riemann sum

$$ g(t)=\int_0^1 \mathrm dk\,e^{it \cos(2\pi k)}$$

Comment: After graphing, $\lim_{L\to\infty}f_L(t)$ seems curiously related to $\text{sinc}(2t)$. I'd even go as far as to say that $\lim_{L\to\infty}f_L(t)\approx \text{sinc}(2t)$

Comment: Correct, $g(t) = \int_0^1 e^{i t \cos 2 \pi x} dx = J_0(t)$.

Comment: @Maxim so I guess it doesn't get better than that